# SlideUp effect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on my website `footer` and would like it if the user clicks `Contact Us` that a yellow div appears from behind the footer.

[Here is what I'm working on so far](http://jsfiddle.net/m3nwm63x/5/) right now, but I can't seem to position the yellow box hidden behind the footer. The yellow area will be roughly 300px in height when visible.

```js
var clicked=true;
$(".one").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked)
    {
        clicked=false;
        $(".two").css({"top": 0});
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".two").css({"top": "40px"});
    }
});
```

```css
footer {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  background:#ccc;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0
}

.container {
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 60px;
    float:left;
}
.one {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px;
}
.two {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 40px;
    background-color: yellow;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s;
    -moz-transition: top 1s;
    -o-transition: top 1s;
    transition: top 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="two">I slide!<br>And I am higher than the div before me...</div>
</div>

<footer>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="one">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive. Maybe make a picture of the intended result. I don't really understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one. It uses jQuery animate to slide.

http://jsfiddle.net/armqc25a/

**JS**

```
var clicked=true;
$(".one").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked)
    {
        clicked=false;
        $(".container").animate({"bottom": "0px"});
    }
    else
    {
        clicked=true;
        $(".container").animate({"bottom": "40px"});
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
footer {
  width:100%;
  background:#ccc;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
  height: 40px;
  left:0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.container {
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.one {
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightblue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.two {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s;
    -moz-transition: top 1s;
    -o-transition: top 1s;
    transition: top 1s;
}
```

Comment: Nice effect. Only one problem. make `clicked=false;` So, it will slide on first click. http://jsfiddle.net/armqc25a/2/

Answer (score 4):

Here's work slide:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute; /*add this, and */
    bottom: 20px; /* this*//*pixel based on what you wish*/
}
```

**UPDATED DEMO:**
Check Update Fiddle [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/m3nwm63x/9/)

Comment: sorry, wrong fiddle :D .. pls check my Update fiddle